# Xamarin Forms Sqllite Database not return all records

Tags: database, forms, sqlite, xamarin

I have created an sqlite database in my xamarin forms app. The database is saving records but when i query database to list/show records it only shows a few of them, not all. When i query the database using the following code, it will show 1 record with first query, 2 records with second query, 5 records with third query and 6 records with 4th query of the same code to pull same records with the database.

```
List<Words> abc = await App.Database.GetWordsAsync();
System.Console.WriteLine("abccount: " + abc.Count);
foreach (var abc1 in abc)
{
   System.Console.WriteLine("abcitem: " + abc1.Word + " - ID: " + abc1.ID);
}
List<Words> abc2 = await App.Database.GetWordsAsync();
System.Console.WriteLine("abc3count: " + abc2.Count);
foreach (var abc3 in abc2)
{
   System.Console.WriteLine("abc3item: " + abc3.Word + " - ID: " + abc3.ID);
}
```

The Results are following:

```
08-31 10:00:40 I/mono-stdout(25307): abc1count: 1
08-31 10:00:40 I/mono-stdout(25307): abc1item: ass - ID: 1

08-31 10:00:40 I/mono-stdout(25307): abc2count: 2
08-31 10:00:40 I/mono-stdout(25307): abc2item: ass - ID: 1
08-31 10:00:40 I/mono-stdout(25307): abc2item: blackhead - ID: 2

08-31 10:00:40 I/mono-stdout(25307): abccount: 5
08-31 10:00:40 I/mono-stdout(25307): abcitem: ass - ID: 1
08-31 10:00:40 I/mono-stdout(25307): abcitem: blackhead - ID: 2
08-31 10:00:40 I/mono-stdout(25307): abcitem: bozo - ID: 3
08-31 10:00:40 I/mono-stdout(25307): abcitem: ego - ID: 4
08-31 10:00:40 I/mono-stdout(25307): abcitem: oaf - ID: 5

08-31 10:00:40 I/mono-stdout(25307): abc3count: 6
08-31 10:00:40 I/mono-stdout(25307): abc3item: ass - ID: 1
08-31 10:00:40 I/mono-stdout(25307): abc3item: blackhead - ID: 2
08-31 10:00:40 I/mono-stdout(25307): abc3item: bozo - ID: 3
08-31 10:00:40 I/mono-stdout(25307): abc3item: ego - ID: 4
08-31 10:00:40 I/mono-stdout(25307): abc3item: oaf - ID: 5
08-31 10:00:40 I/mono-stdout(25307): abc3item: redfish - ID: 6
```

My Database connection in App.xaml.cs is following:

```
        public static WordSearchDatabase Database
        {
            get
            {
                if (database == null)
                {
                    database = new WordSearchDatabase(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "wordsearch.db3"));
                }
                return database;
            }
        }
```

My Database query Interface is as following:

```
    public class WordSearchDatabase
    {
        readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection database;

        public WordSearchDatabase(string dbPath)
        {
            database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
            database.CreateTableAsync<Words>().Wait();
        }

        public Task<List<Words>> GetWordsAsync()
        {
            return database.Table<Words>().ToListAsync();
        }
    }
```

Can anyone please tell me why the same query GetWordsAsync pulls different amount of records from database each time i call it.

Answer (score 0):

The `Concole.WriteLine` cause the error. You could use `Debug.Writeline` instead.

**Code:**

```
List<Words> abc = await App.Database.GetWordsAsync();

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("abccount: " + abc.Count);
        foreach (var abc1 in abc)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("abcitem: " + abc1.Word + " - ID: " + abc1.ID);
        }

        List<Words> abc2 = await App.Database.GetWordsAsync();

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("abc3count: " + abc2.Count);
        foreach (var abc3 in abc2)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("abc3item: " + abc3.Word + " - ID: " + abc3.ID);
        }
```

**My result:**

[image]

We could use `Console.WriteLine` in console applications where it belongs, and use `Debug.WriteLine` everywhere else.